# Filter associated records before associated_against with pg search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pg-search

I'm using pg_search gem in my multilingual rails application and i'm searching my posts like this:

```
  pg_search_scope :search_by_term, :associated_against => {
    :post_translations => :title
  }
```

I have language_id column on my post_translation model which holds locale value ("en" or "es").
Simply, i would like to pass locale and filter post_translations by language_id before search. I went through pg_search documentation and found something like:

```
class Jalopy < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PgSearch
  multisearchable :against => [:make, :model],
                  :if => lambda { |record| record.model_year > 1970 }
end
```

but i can't make it work on associated search.